# How to use a @Produces List both in JSF view and CDI Beans

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, jpa-2.0, cdi

I have a CDI based Web application which displays in a dataTable a list of Tickets that is produced in my ProducerBean:

```
@Produces
@Named
public List<Tickets> getTickets() {     
   return tickets;
}

<h:dataTable var="tickets" value="#{tickets}" >
    . . . 
</h:dataTable>
```

This works perfectly, however I need to use this List of Tickets ("tickets") beyond JSF EL.

Another CDI Bean which is referenced in the same page uses:

```
@Inject
private List <Tickets> tickets;
```

However the list of tickets injected is empty. I still can query again the Tickets via JPA, however I'd like to reuse that List I have produced. Is it possible to do it ? 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that at injection time, the `tickets` field of the first bean is empty. The injection is performed at bean instantiation, so make sure you instantiate the `tickets` field properly inside the `@PostConstruct` method of the first bean.